# add two columns (row wise) in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to learn Apache Pig. I am sorry if its a lame question.

I have three columns `sitename`, `upcount` and `downcount`.

When I use `describe res`, I get: `res: {sitename: chararray,upcount: int,downcount: int}`

What I am trying to do is find site-up percentage of `upcount` by `upcount/(upcount+downcount)`
I am unable to figure how do I achieve it. I tried following:

`res_sum = foreach res generate sitename, upcount+downcount;`

But it gave following error:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias res_sum

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias res_sum
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:935)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:927)
    ... 13 more
================================================================================
```

Comment: Post your entire script,sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please post snippet of your input file as it depends on how you load data into the variable from the file and structure of your input file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
res_sum = foreach res generate sitename, (upcount + downcount) as ud_sum;
```

if it doesn't work - show your entire script